# How to buffer stream when the video is paused with flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming, red5

I need a feature of allowing buffering the video when it's paused, which I cannot find how to do it directly...

I notice that, when I pause the video, the event "NetStream.Buffer.Flush" is triggered. And according to the language reference: "Data has finished streaming, and the remaining buffer will be emptied.", I have to re-buffer it, right? However, also according to the reference, it shouldn't stop buffering:

> Starting with Flash Player 9.0.115.0,
>   Flash Player no longer clears the
>   buffer when NetStream.pause() is
>   called. This behavior is called "smart
>   pause". Before Flash Player 9.0.115.0,
>   Flash Player waited for the buffer to
>   fill up before resuming playback,
>   which often caused a delay.

I'm using Flash Professional to do the debugging, and the traced version number is: MAC 10,0,22,91; and for the streaming server, I use red5. And if you're interested with my code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/kwTfiEH9

I'm now totally confused. Any push is appreciated very much!

Comment: I just saw a bug report on red5 site: http://red5.org/ticket/656
 
But I don't see anyone of the team replies, don't know whether it is a bug either...
 
Still need help.
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[here's an example on wondefl.net based on your code](http://wonderfl.net/c/3dVV)

Comment: thanks. but it's for progressive download not for rtmp stream.