# How does netflix stop buffering/downloading stream when the video is paused?

Tags: javascript, flash, video-streaming, mp4

In Netflix when pause is clicked, how does Netflix stop buffering or in other words "stop downloading the stream"?
When "play" is clicked, the stream buffering resumes.

The basic aim to stop all buffering and reduce any load on the servers, if the user pauses the player.

We are planning on streaming mp4 video using wowza.

We do not have a player yet, but this is one of the requirements. What can I use to develop this feature?

This is the most minimal information I have right now. I can give more answers if you need more information.

Some links I found, but they weren't helpful.
[How do I stop my mediaelement.js player from downloading when it is paused/stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130017/how-do-i-stop-my-mediaelement-js-player-from-downloading-when-it-is-paused-stopp) 
[How to buffer stream when the video is paused with flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319818/how-to-buffer-stream-when-the-video-is-paused-with-flash)

Comment: A true streaming protocol typically has a buffer size that it keeps full of video to be played.  When the buffer is not full, it downloads more video.  When the buffer fills up, it stops downloading until there is more room in the buffer.  Since it's the client managing this buffer, the client just stops requesting more segments of the video when the buffer is full or sends a signal to the server to stop sending more video.  When the user hits the pause button, the buffer fills up and thus the client stops downloading more.  Exact details may vary by protocol, but this is the general idea.